# is it a single variable probability density function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

is it a single variable probability density function?
$$f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
 e^{3x} , &\rm{~~if~~} x \leq 0\\
  1 - \frac{2}{3}x ,&\rm{~~if~~}  0 < x \leq 1\\
0,   &\rm{~~if~~}  x > 1\\
\end{array}\right.$$

I checked, the definite integral of f(x) from -infinity to infinity is 0.
$f(x)\geq 0$

it's limits to infinity and -infinity equal to 0.
It is continuous from left.

There is a 'bump' in the function, because $f(1)=1/3$ and
$f(x>1)=0$
So is it not a problem, because it only has to be continuous from the left, is it correct?

Thank you

Comment: Please read this before posting: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to better format your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A density function is a non-negative measurable function whose integral is $1$. Continuity is not required. (You are probably confusing density function with distribution function). Here the integral is $\frac 1 3 +(1-\frac 1 3) +0=1$ so $f$ is a density function.

Comment: Thank you Kavi Rama! Yes, I confused the continous property.